# How to Catch Connection Issues to Web3 Provider using Web3.js

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, javascript, ganache, web3-providers

My node.js script is able to successfully connect to the Web3 provider when both the private key (using [`truffle-privatekey-provider`](https://github.com/nosuchip/truffle-privatekey-provider)) and the provider host URL are correct.

```
let privateKey = ...,
    providerUrl = ...
const provider = new PrivateKeyProvider(privateKey, providerUrl)
const web3 = new Web3(provider)

try {
    await web3.eth.net.isListening();
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Error connecting to provider')
}
console.log('Connected!');
```

**Problem:** However when the provider host URL is incorrect, the above code does not throw any errors and simply gets stuck in the `await` statement.

Is there a way to know when there is an issue connecting to the provider host?

Comment: I think you could add a timeout function to the await, but I think that's about it.

Comment: @GrandFleet What timeout duration will you suggest? 10 seconds?

Comment: 10 seconds makes sense, but considering how crypto is starting to take off in smaller communities without traditionally banking options and with slower internet it may be a good idea to have a 30 second timeout duration.

Comment: @GrandFleet How can we use `setTimeout` together with `web3.eth.net.isListening()`? Cant seem to figure out the code

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do that is setTimeout, but if you were to use setTimeout I think you could convert your try catch to then catch for promises.
See 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813405/async-await-function-does-not-wait-for-settimeout-to-finish, but I don't know the answer off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.race` to get the result of the first returned promise, where the first promise is your `web3.eth.net.isListening()` and the second is an error thrown after a timeout.

```
// Returns promise or throws error after timeout reached
const timeout = (prom, time) => Promise.race([prom, new Promise((_r, rej) => setTimeout(rej, time))]);

try {
  // Allow isListening to run for 10 seconds
  await timeout(web3.eth.net.isListening(), 10000);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error connecting to provider')
}
```